# Function to get permalink of custom post type archives?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Is there a function that will return the permalink to a custom post types archives that is available to use in WordPress?

Something like:

`get_cpt_permalink("events")` which will return `http://example.com/events/` when `has_archive => true` on it.

If not what would I need to home brew my own? I'm thinking I would need to read `$wp_rewrite` and use something along the lines of `$wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct('events');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for `get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type );`